# Is there an easy way to TeX geometric pictures?

Tags: diagrams

Say I want to include geometry graphics such as the following in a document:
[image]

I don't merely want to import preexisting figures, I want to be able to draw my own corresponding to a solution I may write up. Is there a package or something that allows one to do this relatively easily?

Answer (score 33, accepted):

tkz-euclide arrives on the ctan servers. You can get it  with ftp from tug.org

ftp://tug.org/tex-archive/macros/latex/contrib/tkz/ you need to install tkz-base and tkz-euclide. These packages work only with pgf 2.1

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[upright]{fourier} 
\usepackage[usenames,dvipsnames]{xcolor}
\usepackage{tkz-euclide} 
\usetkzobj{all} 
\definecolor{fondpaille}{cmyk}{0,0,0.1,0}
\pagecolor{fondpaille}   
\color{Maroon}  
\tkzSetUpColors[background=fondpaille,text=Maroon]
\thispagestyle{empty}  
                        
\begin{document}
 
 \begin{tikzpicture}
\tkzDefPoint(0,0){A}\tkzDefPoint(6,0){B}
\tkzDefPoint(6,4){C}\tkzDefPoint(0,4){D}
\tkzInterLL(A,C)(B,D)  \tkzGetPoint{I}  
 
\tkzDrawPolygon (A,B,C,D)
\tkzDrawSegments(A,C B,D)
\tkzMarkRightAngles[fill=Maroon!20,size=.3,opacity=.5](D,A,B A,B,C B,C,D C,D,A)
\tkzDrawPoints(A,B,C,D,I)  

\tkzMarkSegments[mark=s||](I,A I,B I,C I,D)
\tkzLabelPoints(A,B) \tkzLabelPoints[above=6pt](I)   
\tkzLabelPoints[above right](C,D)  
\end{tikzpicture}  
\end{document}
```

[image: Image from code sample]

Best regards

Alain Matthes (author of tkz-euclide)
There  are a lot of examples on my site altermundus.fr

Comment: @Alain the user manual is a work of art! Thanks!

Answer (score 17):

Run it with `xelatex`

```
\documentclass{minimal}
\usepackage{pst-eucl}
\begin{document}

\begin{pspicture}(8,5)
\pstGeonode[PosAngle={180,0,0,180}](0,0){A}(6,0){B}(6,4){C}(0,4){D}
\pspolygon[fillstyle=solid,fillcolor=blue!20](A)(B)(C)(D)
\pstInterLL[PointSymbol=square]{A}{C}{B}{D}{E}
\pstSegmentMark{A}{E}\pstSegmentMark{C}{E}
\pstSegmentMark[MarkAngle=-65]{B}{E}\pstSegmentMark[MarkAngle=-65]{D}{E}
\pstRightAngle{C}{B}{A}\pstRightAngle{B}{A}{D}
\pstRightAngle[RightAngleType=german]{D}{C}{B}\pstRightAngle{C}{D}{A}
\end{pspicture}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks Herbert, this seems like a easy thing to implement. May I ask what `PosAngle={180,0,0,180}]` means? What do the arguments specify? Why is it not `PosAngle={90,90,90,90}]`?

Comment: @yunone: makes the setting of the labels easier. It is the angle where the A,B,C,and D are printed. With all set to 90 you'll get the A and B half inside the frame. A `-90 -90 90 90` would make sense

Comment: Instructions for LyX users: 1. Download and install pst-eucl from here: http://www.ctan.org/tex-archive/graphics/pstricks/contrib/pst-eucl .  2. go to Document->Settings->Document Preamble, insert "\usepackage{pst-eucl}".   3. Click Ctrl+L, add the tex code from "\begin{pspicture}(8,5)" to "\end{pspicture}".  4. Click Ctrl+T to convert to PS. You should see a nice rectangle.

Answer (score 7):

There are at least two packages that I know of, one based on `pstricks`: the `pst-eucl` package (which should be part of your TeX distribution) and one based on `TikZ`: the `tkz-euclide` package available here: [tkz-euclide](http://www.altermundus.fr/pages/download.html) (or on CTAN). Unfortunately for the latter, the documentation is only in French, but there are plenty of examples so this may not be too much of a problem.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, Alan. I'm not too familiar with pstricks. Can I simply say `\usepackage{pst-eucl}` in my preamble after installing it, or do I have to do something with pstricks first?

Comment: @yunone For some of the examples in the documentation you may have to load the `pst-plot` package. But the simple examples should work just with loading `pst-eucl`.  You need to compile your documents with `latex+dvips` instead of `pdflatex`.

Comment: @yunone: Yes, `\usepackage{pst-eucl}` is ok, then you can run `xelatex` to get a pdf, which should be available on all TeX distributions. alternatively run `pdflatex -shell-escape <file>` with `\usepackage{auto-pst-pdf}`. There is no need for running `latex+dvips`

Answer (score 5):

[Geogebra](http://www.geogebra.org/cms/) and [asymptote](http://asymptote.sourceforge.net/) are further tools which could be used in this regard.

Comment: It's worth pointing out that GeoGebra exports TikZ code.

Comment: It's also worth pointing out that GeoGebra exports PSTricks codes.

Comment: It's also worth pointing out that GeoGebra exports Asymptote codes.