# Need recommendations for a drawing tool in LaTeX

Tags: tikz-pgf, diagrams

I have never used a graphing tool in LaTeX but now I need to draw a picture. It is not very complicated: an xy-plane with axis; a number of points; a number of straight lines and finally two hyperbolas. My question is what tool I should pick? I have seen TikZ but I am told it takes quite some time before you can actually use it.

Comment: http://tug.org/PSTricks/main.cgi?file=pst-plot/FunctionExamples

Answer (score 25, accepted):

If you are looking for a LaTeX package, use `pgfplots` (based on `TikZ`), or `pst-plot` (part of `PSTricks`). Or you can use any other tools to draw graphs, such as gnuplot, MATLAB, etc.

For Euclidian geometry, `tkz-euclide` or `pst-eucl` package can be used. And I recommend a java program `GeoGebra`, which is really easy to use:

http://www.geogebra.org/cms/

[image: GeoGebra]

Comment: +1 for the use of Geogebra. It is great for geometry and exports tikz code.

Comment: Thank you this not only helped me with what I needed but also in the process I learned a little bit of tikZ!

Comment: GeoGebra is superb in use with LaTeX. I know the person who beat me in making a translation, otherwise I would help the development.

Answer (score 10):

[Inkscape](http://inkscape.org/) is he BIG DADDY of drawing packages. It is extremely powerfull. Since version 0.48 it has the option to export the text and graphics separate so that the figure then can be processed with Latex to create a pdf.  It can be called with command line options. the following is a Windows-DOS batch file to do the job. You can insert your local font setup in "texheader.tex"

`---svgtopdf.bat----`

```
call inkscape.exe -z -D --file=%1.svg --export-pdf=%1-@temp-src.pdf --export-latex

echo \documentclass[10pt]{article}      > %1-@temp-tex.tex
echo \InputIfFileExists{texheader}{}{} >> %1-@temp-tex.tex
echo \usepackage{graphicx}             >> %1-@temp-tex.tex
echo \usepackage{color}                >> %1-@temp-tex.tex
echo \pagestyle{empty}                 >> %1-@temp-tex.tex
echo \begin{document}                  >> %1-@temp-tex.tex
echo \input{%1-@temp-src.pdf_tex}      >> %1-@temp-tex.tex
echo \end{document}                    >> %1-@temp-tex.tex

call pdflatex %1-@temp-tex.tex
call pdfcrop  %1-@temp-tex.pdf %1.pdf

del %1-@temp-src.*
del %1-@temp-tex.*
```

[jpgfdraw](http://theoval.cmp.uea.ac.uk/~nlct/jpgfdraw/) can export to pgf.

[Ipe](http://tclab.kaist.ac.kr/ipe/) can export to eps and pdf and uses Latex for text.

[TpX](http://tpx.sourceforge.net/) Is also quite usefull to include Latex text.

[LaTeXDraw](http://latexdraw.sourceforge.net/) generates PSTricks graphics

Answer (score 9):

You can use tkz-fct, tkz-base and tkz-euclide. All the packages are based on pgf/tikz.
tkz-fct uses gnuplot to get points. It' s possible to get intersection  of the straight lines and the two hyperbolas.

Comment: Welcome to tex.sx! Although your user name is different from your "real world name", it is probably not recommendable to sign your posts with the latter: It's really not usual here; just stick with the user name that appears automatically in the lower right corner. Only in [this answer](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/9652/is-there-an-easy-way-to-tex-geometric-pictures/9667#9667) of yours it was quite good since this gave us valuable extra information `:-)`

Comment: @ Hendrik Thanks for welcome and thanks for your remark . I am a bit lost in this new world :)

Comment: Hope you're finding your orientation. One piece of help: Don't put a space between "@" and "Hendrik". With the space, I wasn't notified of your comment.

Comment: @Hendrik Thanks ! Yes  I begin to find my orientation. I read yesterday a answer about : "how to use @" and this morning I discover the letter symbol at the top of the page :)

Answer (score 4):

For drawings and plots I recommend TikZ and PGFplots.

- TikZ examples are at [texample.net](http://www.texample.net/tikz/examples/)
- PGFplots examples are at [sf.net](http://pgfplots.sf.net)

There is also an example with [intersections](http://www.texample.net/tikz/examples/intersection-of/):
[image: Intersection]

Answer (score 4):

PSTricks has a package named [pst-eucl](http://mirrors.ctan.org/graphics/pstricks/contrib/pst-eucl/pst-eucl-doc.pdf) that provides us with many interfaces to draw euclidean geometry objects as follows. PostScript language, that is used internally by PSTricks, allows us to do more complex mathematical calculation. It is worth investing your time to learn PSTricks. :-)

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

Can GeoGebra do these diagrams easily and accurately?

Answer (score 2):

[TexGraph](http://texgraph.tuxfamily.org/) in French only I guess

Comment: Do you know how TexGraph compares to Asymptote? It seems a very nice tool (especially given `tikz` weakness in 3D), but only four posts on the whole website mention TexGraph!