# Define a variable in TikZ

Tags: tikz-pgf

I guess this is a very simple question, but I couldn't find the answer... How can I define a variable in TikZ? I want to have something like, for example:

```
\draw[->] (x1,y1)--(x2,y2);
```

Such that `x1,x2,y1,y2` are defined somewhere else and can be changed in order to adjust the picture.

Should be simple, right?

Comment: Since you chose the `pgfplots` tag, do you have anything particular in mind that concerns drawing things in `pgfplots`. There are some special things inside its `axis` environments, like the `axis cs` and `rel axis cs` coordinate systems that might be helpful for you, so maybe you could edit your question to give more details (or remove the `pgfplots` tag if you actually meant TikZ in general).

Comment: The "right" answer to this depends on how you envision specifying `x1`, `x2`, `y1`, and `y2`.  If you just want to vary them explicitly, then the `\newcommand` approach is as good as any.  If they are coordinates, then the `\coordinate` approach is best.  But if they are to be computed from something else, then something a little more complicated (but not much) is needed; however, exactly what depends on how you want to specify them.

Comment: @Andrew: Can you elaborate regarding the last option you mentioned? I want to use TikZ for drawing/plotting mathematical objects. For example, provide a point and a slope and plot the corresponding line (or at least a segment of it). Then, I want to compute and plot intersection of two such lines and so on and so forth..

Comment: Maybe Alain Matthes' package `tkz-euclide` that he refers to in [an answer to another question](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/9652/is-there-an-easy-way-to-tex-geometric-pictures/9667#9667) could be helpful for you? There are quite a few examples on [his website](http://www.altermundus.fr/pages/euclide.html).

Comment: @Jake: I'm looking for something more straightforward, where I can "program" my plot as directly as possible, relaying on TikZ. Moreover, I failed to install tkz-euclid on my mac...

Answer (score 86, accepted):

```
\begin{tikzpicture} 
\coordinate (A) at (2,3);
\coordinate (B) at (2,5);
\draw[->] (A)--(B) ;
\end{tikzpicture}
```

You can add

`\newcommand\XA{2}` etc. and then `\coordinate (A) at (\XA,\YA);`

Comment: Note that `\coordinate` s are just special `\node` s and they are defined global, i.e. you could define `A` and `B` in another `tikzpicture`, e.g. an otherwise empty one at the beginning of the document.

Comment: @Martin: [You don't need the space before the "s" anymore](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/863/how-do-i-mark-inline-code).

Answer (score 78):

I'm using `\def\x{1068}` to have `x` as a variable in [my script to generate scalebars](http://www.ana.unibe.ch/~haberthuer/latex/tikz/scalebar) onto images with TikZ. That works like a charm for me.

A working example is pasted below, even though the image does not look very nice :)

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[demo]{graphicx}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{siunitx}
\usepackage[graphics,tightpage,active]{preview}
\PreviewEnvironment{tikzpicture}
\newcommand{\imsize}{\linewidth}
\newlength\imagewidth % needed for scalebars
\newlength\imagescale % ditto
\begin{document}%
%-------------
\pgfmathsetlength{\imagewidth}{\imsize}%
\pgfmathsetlength{\imagescale}{\imagewidth/1728}%
\def\x{1068}% scalebar-x at golden ratio of x=1728px
\def\y{320}% scalebar-y at 90% of height of y=356px
\def\shadow{11}% shadow parameter for scalebar
\begin{tikzpicture}[x=\imagescale,y=-\imagescale]
\clip (0,0) rectangle (1728,356);
    \node[anchor=north west, inner sep=0pt, outer sep=0pt] at (0,0) {\includegraphics[width=\imagewidth]{image}};
    % 279px = 1.7819mm > 100px = 638um > 78px = 500um, 16px = 100um
    \draw[|-|,blue,thick] (791,151) -- (1020,311) node [sloped,midway,above,fill=white,semitransparent,text opacity=1] {\SI{1.7819}{\milli\meter} (1204px) TEMPORARY!};
\draw[|-|,thick] (\x+\shadow,\y+\shadow) -- (\x+78+\shadow,\y+\shadow) node [midway, above] {\SI{500}{\micro\meter}};
    \draw[|-|,white,thick] (\x,\y) -- (\x+78,\y) node [midway,above] {\SI{500}{\micro\meter}};
    \draw[color=red, anchor=south west] (0,356) node [fill=white, semitransparent] {Legend} node {Legend};
\end{tikzpicture}%
%-------------
\end{document}%
```

Comment: Yes, so to be clear your answer is `\def\varname{initialValue}`. I think your example is far too complicated to show use of a simple variable.

Comment: You're of course right that the answer could be written much shorter, but I wanted to show a full example on how I use `\dev\varname{initialValue}`.

Comment: Then, how we can use the defined variable somewhere else where we need to divide it by, for example, 2? `\varname/2`? `\varname*0.5`?

Comment: @Rasoul Yes, exactly. I'm using it like `\x+78+\shadow` in the fifth line from bottom. Dividing works too. Try changing said line to `\draw[|-|,white,thick] (\x/2,\y) -- (\x/2+78,\y) node [midway,above] {\SI{500}{\micro\meter}};` and you see that the white scalebar moves...

Comment: How do we avoid overwriting existing LaTeX macros? I'm afraid I'm going to blow up my entire book if this happens.

Answer (score 74):

Tikz offers a powerful solution to dealing with variables through the library `math` ([TikZ version >= 3.00](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/218664/tikz-library-math))

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\begin{document}

\usetikzlibrary{math} %needed tikz library

% Variables must be declared in a tikzmath environment but
% can be used outside (almost anywhere)
% Do not forget SEMICOLONS after each command (!)
\tikzmath{\x1 = 1; \y1 =1; 
% Computations are also possible
\x2 = \x1 + 1; \y2 =\y1 +3; } 

% Using the variables for drawing
\begin{tikzpicture}
    \draw[very thick, -stealth] (\x1, \y1)--(\x2, \y2);
\end{tikzpicture}

% Using the variables in math and text modi
The coordinates of the second point are:

$x_2 = \x2$ and $y_2 =$ \y2

% Note that the name of the variables, e.g., \x1, 
% can contain a number as the LAST name characters (!)
% That would be not allowed with a \newcommand definition
\end{document}
```

[image: The result of the code above]

See also [this answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/30081/how-can-i-sum-two-values-and-store-the-result-in-other-variable/#455441) for more examples with different uses.

Comment: Thanks! I think this is a lot better approach than cluttering the general namespace with \def  or \newcommand variables

Comment: I get an output from tikzmath in the pdf output.

Comment: @AntonioSesto Sorry, but I do not know exactly what you mean :\. The code above works flawlessly when the needed packages are installed. You will have to pose a new question in TeX-StackExchange ;)

Comment: One missing remark: when using numbers in the name, they have to be the last characters, otherwise, an error will be returned.

Comment: @Diaa Your remark has improved the answer. Thanks!

Comment: @ChrisSewell You're not really cluttering the general namespace since `\def` won't affect anything outside the local group. And I don't think this library was even available when most of the answers were written (but I'm not certain about that).

Answer (score 45):

I use `\pgfmathsetmacro{VARName}{VARValue}` inside a `tikzpicture` environment.

For example:

```
\begin{tikzpicture}

%VARIABLES
\pgfmathsetmacro{\PHI}{-15}

% Now use \PHI anywhere you want -15 to appear,
% can also be used in calculations like 2*\PHI

\end{tikzpicture}
```

Comment: The number is not special `\begin{tikzpicture}
\def\PHI{-15}
\node (o) at (0,0) {o};
\node (a) at (\PHI mm,\PHI mm) {a};
\end{tikzpicture}` also works. However this command is useful to store the result of a mathematical operation such as `\pgfmathsetmacro{\PHI}{cos(60)}`

Comment: Yes, I'm aware you can embed an entire macro in `\pgfmathsetmacro` but there is no harm in using it for constants.

Comment: Two remarks : first it's more complicated, the definition of `\pgfmathsetmacro`: `\begingroup%
  \pgfmathsetlength\pgfmath@x{#2}%
  \edef#1{\pgfmath@tonumber{\pgfmath@x}}%
  \pgfmath@smuggleone{#1}%
 \endgroup% `. The second remark you can use `\pgfmathsetmacro` outside  a `tikzpicture` environment.

Answer (score 7):

Building on the example in the comments to the question, here's a more complicated example that uses some computations to find the desired coordinates and then uses them.

```
\documentclass{minimal}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{intersections}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
\draw[gray,thin] (-1,-1) grid (5,5);
\draw[ultra thick,->] (-1,0)  -- (5.2,0);
\draw[ultra thick,->] (0,-1) -- (0,5.2);
\clip (-1,-1) rectangle (5,5);
\foreach \m/\c/\col in {
  3/{(2,0)}/blue,
  2/{(1,1)}/red,
  -.25/{(0,4)}/green%
} {
  % Separate the coordinate \c into x and y components
  \fill[\col] \c circle (2pt);
  \pgfgetlastxy{\vx}{\vy}
  % Work out the y-height at one end of the line
  \pgfmathsetmacro{\ey}{\vy + \m*(5 cm -\vx)}
  % Work out the y-height at the other end of the line
  \pgfmathsetmacro{\by}{\vy - \m*(\vx+1 cm)}
  \draw[thick,\col] (-1,\by pt) -- (5,\ey pt);
}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image: lines from slope and point]