# Working with variables in Tikz

Tags: tikz-pgf, programming, calculations

### Background

I'm fairly new to tikz, and I am currently trying to create a figure with variables to easily change dimensions when needed. I am however having some troubles when attempting to apply arithmetic to my variables.

### Problem

As I understand it `\def\VARNAME{INITIALVALUE}`, defines a variable. Using `\def\a{2.4}` as an example, `2*\a` will evaluate as `4.8` as expected whilst `2\a` will however evaluate as `22.4`. I seem to hit a snag however when I attempt to multiply a variable which I have defined as a sum of two other variables.

Is what I'm trying to do not possible using the `\def` command or am I missing something? Is it preferred to instead use `\newlength` and `\setlength`? or perhaps `\pgfmathsetmacro`?

---

### MWE:

```
\documentclass[tikz]{standalone}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}

\def\thickness{5mm}  
\def\lambda{9cm}   
\def\slotW{5mm}      
\def\secW{\lambda/2-\slotW}

\draw(0,  -\thickness) rectangle +(\secW,-\thickness)    ; % as expected
\draw(0,-2*\thickness) rectangle +(2*\secW,-\thickness)  ; % this seems to evaluate to 2*\lambda/2-\slotW not 2*(\lambda/2-\slotW) as I expected
\draw(0,-3*\thickness) rectangle +(2*(\secW),-\thickness); % this won't evaluate at all

\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Welcome to [tex.se]!  You should load the tikz calc library: `\tikzloadlibrary{calc}` and do calculations within in `($...$)` constructs.

Comment: You need `+({2*(\secW)},-\thickness)`, otherwise the closing parenthesis after `\secW` is seen as the closing parenthesis of the coordinate.

Comment: Thanks @TorbjørnT. ! A concise explanation of why my code didn't work and how to solve it is exactly what I wanted.
If you'd submit an answer I'd gladly accept it.

Comment: Don't have time right now, and this is guaranteed to be a duplicate, so if someone finds a good candidate, we may as well close I think.

Comment: Also http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/12859/define-a-variable-in-tikz is interesting, with more options

Comment: Accepted duplicate, the second suggestion is interesting as well (my original source for understanding variables), but not as concise and to the point as your first suggestion @Rmano.