# Define a tikz variable only inside the current tikzpicture

Tags: tikz-pgf, calculations, coordinates

I want to "define" a variable inside my tikzpicture. This [answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/362672/180429) gives a solution for how to do that, using the `math` library.

The thing I am concerned with is that when I assign `\x1` the value of `1`, let's say, this value is defined globally across my latex document.

So if I want to draw two rather similar graphics, which for both it is comfortable to use the name `x1` to describe a specific length, then I need to either

- come up with a new name for this length, such as `x1` and `x1new`
- or I need to run over the definition for `\x1=1` later in the document with `\x1=2`.

My question is whether there is a way to define a variable and assign it a value **just for the current** `tikzpicture` environment?

A MWE:

```latex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{math}
\tikzmath{\x1 = 2; \y1=1;} %%%% <<----- First definition
\begin{document}
In this lecture we will talk about complex numbers.

The complex number $2+\mathrm{i}$ can be pictured in the following way:

\begin{tikzpicture}
\draw[step=.5cm,gray,very thin] (-2.4,-2.4) grid (2.4,2.4);
\draw [-latex] (-2.5,0) -- (2.5,0);
\draw [-latex] (0,-2.5) -- (0,2.5);
\draw [thick, - latex] (0,0) -- (\x1,\y1);
\end{tikzpicture}

An example for a vector with a negative argument is the following:

\begin{tikzpicture}
\tikzmath{\y1=-1;}  %%%% <<----- run over the previous value of y1
\draw[step=.5cm,gray,very thin] (-2.4,-2.4) grid (2.4,2.4);
\draw [-latex] (-2.5,0) -- (2.5,0);
\draw [-latex] (0,-2.5) -- (0,2.5);
\draw [thick, - latex] (0,0) -- (\x1,\y1);
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Define your variable inside a group

Comment: Right. Do you want to write it as an answer?

Comment: No, there is no code in your question so I would have to come up with a minimal working example first ... too lazy for that

Comment: @samcarter_is_at_topanswers.xyz Added

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you make your definition inside a group around your tikzpicture, it will only define the variable inside this group.

You can explicitly add a group by e.g. using `{...}` or you can place your definition inside the tikpicture, which automatically forms a group.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{math}
\tikzmath{\x1 = 2; \y1=1;} %%%% <<----- First definition
\begin{document}
In this lecture we will talk about complex numbers.

The complex number $2+\mathrm{i}$ can be pictured in the following way:

{
\tikzmath{\x1 = 1;}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\draw[step=.5cm,gray,very thin] (-2.4,-2.4) grid (2.4,2.4);
\draw [-latex] (-2.5,0) -- (2.5,0);
\draw [-latex] (0,-2.5) -- (0,2.5);
\draw [thick, - latex] (0,0) -- (\x1,\y1);
\end{tikzpicture}
}

An example for a vector with a negative argument is the following:

\begin{tikzpicture}
\tikzmath{\y1=-1;}  %%%% <<----- run over the previous value of y1
\draw[step=.5cm,gray,very thin] (-2.4,-2.4) grid (2.4,2.4);
\draw [-latex] (-2.5,0) -- (2.5,0);
\draw [-latex] (0,-2.5) -- (0,2.5);
\draw [thick, - latex] (0,0) -- (\x1,\y1);
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```