# Draw a rectangle with partly invisible edges, only corners

Tags: tikz-pgf, tikz-node

I want to create the following:

[image]

That is, a rectangle with partly invisible edges.

How can I do that?

What I have now:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\node[draw,rectangle,minimum width=8cm,minimum height=2cm] {lorem ipsum};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Less elegant than Jasper Habicht's answer, but if you only need that box maybe it is simpler.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}

\newcommand{\mybox}[2][black]{%
  \begin{tikzpicture}
    \node[rectangle,minimum width=8cm,minimum height=2cm, font=\Large] (A) {#2};
    \draw[#1, line width = 3pt] 
      (A.north west) -- +(.3,0) -- (A.north west) -- +(0,-.4) 
      (A.north east) -- +(-.3,0) -- (A.north east) -- +(0,-.4) 
      (A.south west) -- +(.3,0) -- (A.south west) -- +(0,.4) 
      (A.south east) -- +(-.3,0) -- (A.south east) -- +(0,.4) 
      ;
   \end{tikzpicture}%
}

\begin{document}
\mybox{lorem ipsum}
\vspace{1cm}

\mybox[red]{lorem ipsum}
\end{document}
```

[image]

*EDIT: parametric length*

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}

\newcommand{\mybox}[3][black]{%
  \begin{tikzpicture}
    \node[rectangle,minimum width=8cm,minimum height=2cm, font=\Large] (A) {#2};
    \draw[#1, line width = 3pt] 
      (A.north west) -- +(#3,0) -- (A.north west) -- +(0,-#3) 
      (A.north east) -- +(-#3,0) -- (A.north east) -- +(0,-#3) 
      (A.south west) -- +(#3,0) -- (A.south west) -- +(0,#3) 
      (A.south east) -- +(-#3,0) -- (A.south east) -- +(0,#3) 
      ;
   \end{tikzpicture}%
}

\begin{document}
\mybox{lorem ipsum}{.3}
\vspace{1cm}

\mybox[red]{lorem ipsum}{.3}
\vspace{1cm}

\mybox{lorem ipsum}{.4}
\vspace{1cm}

\mybox[green]{lorem ipsum}{.4}
\vspace{1cm}

\mybox{lorem ipsum}{.7}
\vspace{1cm}

\mybox[cyan]{lorem ipsum}{.7}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: I am looking for a way to change the lengths `.3` and `.4` more quickly. Can you show me a way to define a new "dimensionless" length to be used instead of the explicit numbers that are used now? Doing `\newlength` demands a unit to be assigned to the new length. There isn't any unit in this case. I also want to define this length locally - only inside the current tikzpicture.

Comment: @tush How does this length be? A proportion of the segments?

Comment: Well that's what I am questioning myself. When you say `\draw (0,0) -- (0.3,0);`, `0.3` points, or cm, or what unit?

Comment: @tush The default is cm, but you can use any units you like

Comment: Well then, how can I define a length in the tikzpicture so I can make changes to the many `.3` sizes at once?

Comment: @tush I added a new answer which supports `\mybox[red, x=1.5cm, y=.2cm]{lorem ipsum}`, see https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/683382.

Comment: @tush See my edit with parametric length, is it what you want?

Comment: Is there a way to place this box in the center of the page or at the end?

Comment: @donaastor There are various ways to do it. It's better if you ask a new question with a minimal example. You can also link this question as example.

Answer (score 11):

The best thing would probably be to create your own shape.

Here, it's also much easier to take the `outer sep`s into account.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\pgfset{corners rectangle size/.initial=10pt}
\makeatletter
\pgfdeclareshape{corners rectangle}{%
    \inheritsavedanchors[from=rectangle]%
    \inheritanchorborder[from=rectangle]%
    \inheritanchor[from=rectangle]{north}%
    \inheritanchor[from=rectangle]{north west}%
    \inheritanchor[from=rectangle]{north east}%
    \inheritanchor[from=rectangle]{center}%
    \inheritanchor[from=rectangle]{west}%
    \inheritanchor[from=rectangle]{east}%
    \inheritanchor[from=rectangle]{mid}%
    \inheritanchor[from=rectangle]{mid west}%
    \inheritanchor[from=rectangle]{mid east}%
    \inheritanchor[from=rectangle]{base}%
    \inheritanchor[from=rectangle]{base west}%
    \inheritanchor[from=rectangle]{base east}%
    \inheritanchor[from=rectangle]{south}%
    \inheritanchor[from=rectangle]{south west}%
    \inheritanchor[from=rectangle]{south east}%
    \foregroundpath{
    % store lower right in xa/ya and upper right in xb/yb
      \southwest \pgf@xa=\pgf@x \pgf@ya=\pgf@y
      \northeast \pgf@xb=\pgf@x \pgf@yb=\pgf@y
      \pgfmathsetlength\pgf@xc{\pgfkeysvalueof{/pgf/outer xsep}}%
      \pgfmathsetlength\pgf@yc{\pgfkeysvalueof{/pgf/outer ysep}}%
      \advance\pgf@xa by \pgf@xc \advance\pgf@xb by -\pgf@xc
      \advance\pgf@ya by \pgf@yc \advance\pgf@yb by -\pgf@yc
      \pgfmathsetlength\pgfutil@tempdima{\pgfkeysvalueof{/pgf/corners rectangle size}}%
      \pgfpathmoveto{\pgfqpoint{\dimexpr\pgf@xa+\pgfutil@tempdima}{\pgf@ya}}%
      \pgfpathlineto{\pgfqpoint{\pgf@xa}{\pgf@ya}}%
      \pgfpathlineto{\pgfqpoint{\pgf@xa}{\dimexpr\pgf@ya+\pgfutil@tempdima}}%
      \pgfpathmoveto{\pgfqpoint{\dimexpr\pgf@xa+\pgfutil@tempdima}{\pgf@yb}}%
      \pgfpathlineto{\pgfqpoint{\pgf@xa}{\pgf@yb}}%
      \pgfpathlineto{\pgfqpoint{\pgf@xa}{\dimexpr\pgf@yb-\pgfutil@tempdima}}%
      \pgfpathmoveto{\pgfqpoint{\dimexpr\pgf@xb-\pgfutil@tempdima}{\pgf@ya}}%
      \pgfpathlineto{\pgfqpoint{\pgf@xb}{\pgf@ya}}%
      \pgfpathlineto{\pgfqpoint{\pgf@xb}{\dimexpr\pgf@ya+\pgfutil@tempdima}}%
      \pgfpathmoveto{\pgfqpoint{\dimexpr\pgf@xb-\pgfutil@tempdima}{\pgf@yb}}%
      \pgfpathlineto{\pgfqpoint{\pgf@xb}{\pgf@yb}}%
      \pgfpathlineto{\pgfqpoint{\pgf@xb}{\dimexpr\pgf@yb-\pgfutil@tempdima}}%
      \pgfsetarrowsstart{}%
      \pgfsetarrowsend{}%
    }%
}%
\makeatother
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[minimum width=8cm, minimum height=2cm, nodes=corners rectangle]
\node[draw] {lorem ipsum};
\node[corners rectangle size=15pt, draw=red, thick] at (0, -3) (a) {lorem ipsum};
\foreach \ang in {5,...,20} \draw (a.\ang) --+(\ang:.5);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

---

As an easy workaround, you can make use of `append after command` and the like.

With `\pgfsettransform` we make sure that the same transformation are used that were applied to the node, making this independently from the path those corners are drawn on.

There's no consideration for `outer sep` or the line width.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\tikzset{
  draw corners/.style={
    append after command={\bgroup
      \pgfextra{\pgfsettransform{\csname pgf@sh@nt@\tikzlastnode\endcsname}}
      [to path=|-(\tikztotarget)]
                   ([yshift=-\pgfkeysvalueof{/tikz/draw corners size}]\tikzlastnode.north west)
          edge[#1] ([xshift= \pgfkeysvalueof{/tikz/draw corners size}]\tikzlastnode.north west)
                   ([yshift=-\pgfkeysvalueof{/tikz/draw corners size}]\tikzlastnode.north east)
          edge[#1] ([xshift=-\pgfkeysvalueof{/tikz/draw corners size}]\tikzlastnode.north east)
                   ([yshift= \pgfkeysvalueof{/tikz/draw corners size}]\tikzlastnode.south east)
          edge[#1] ([xshift=-\pgfkeysvalueof{/tikz/draw corners size}]\tikzlastnode.south east)
                   ([yshift= \pgfkeysvalueof{/tikz/draw corners size}]\tikzlastnode.south west)
          edge[#1] ([xshift= \pgfkeysvalueof{/tikz/draw corners size}]\tikzlastnode.south west)
      \egroup}},
  draw corners size/.initial=10pt}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[rectangle, minimum width=8cm, minimum height=2cm]
\path[rotate=30]node[rotate=10, draw corners] at (0,0) {lorem ipsum};
\tikzset{draw corners size=15pt}
\node[scale=.5, draw corners={red, thick}] at (0,-3) {lorem ipsum};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

---

You could also use `path picture` to avoid nesting paths:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}

\tikzset{
    draw corners/.style={
        path picture={
            \draw[#1]
                (path picture bounding box.north west) 
                    +(\pgflinewidth,-\pgfkeysvalueof{/tikz/draw corners size}) |- 
                    +(\pgfkeysvalueof{/tikz/draw corners size},-\pgflinewidth)
                (path picture bounding box.south west) 
                    +(\pgflinewidth,\pgfkeysvalueof{/tikz/draw corners size}) |- 
                    +(\pgfkeysvalueof{/tikz/draw corners size},\pgflinewidth)
                (path picture bounding box.north east) 
                    +(-\pgflinewidth,-\pgfkeysvalueof{/tikz/draw corners size}) |- 
                    +(-\pgfkeysvalueof{/tikz/draw corners size},-\pgflinewidth)
                (path picture bounding box.south east) 
                    +(-\pgflinewidth,\pgfkeysvalueof{/tikz/draw corners size}) |- 
                    +(-\pgfkeysvalueof{/tikz/draw corners size},\pgflinewidth);
        }
    },
    draw corners size/.initial=10pt
}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}

\node[draw corners, rectangle, minimum width=8cm, minimum height=2cm] 
    at (0,0) {lorem ipsum};

\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: One should not use paths in `\pgfextra`. To see why, add for instance `rotate=30` to one of your nodes. You can use a `path picture` instead.

Comment: @Displayname You are right: transformations have to be handled with care this way (but you could say `\node[rotate=10, draw corners={rotate=10}] {};`). However, you cannot rotate the node when using `path picture` either without getting strange results, at least not when using `path picture bounding box`.

Comment: Thanks! The `outer sep` is my weak spot it seems =)

Answer (score 9):

One option whithout tikz: just a table.

[image: mwe]

```
\documentclass[twocolumn]{article}
\usepackage{lipsum,parskip}
\usepackage{tabulary}
\def\notecorner#1{\medskip\par{\noindent\centering\begin{tabulary}{\linewidth}{cJc}
\cline{1-1}\cline{3-3}\multicolumn{1}{|c}{}&&\multicolumn{1}{c|}{}\\
&#1&\\\multicolumn{1}{|c}{} &  & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{}\\
\cline{1-1}\cline{3-3}\end{tabulary}\medskip\par}}
\begin{document}

\lipsum[1][1-5]

\notecorner{\lipsum[2][1]}

\lipsum[3][1-5]

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 5):

Here you have two more solutions.

The first one uses `path picture` option to define a `TiKZ` style with all node's corners. This way the extra path proposed by CarlaTeX is not needed.

The second defines a `tcolorbox` instead of a `TiKZ` node.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}

\usepackage[most]{tcolorbox}

\usepackage{lipsum}

\newtcolorbox{corners}[1][]{%
    enhanced, colback=white, sharp corners,
    colframe=blue,
    frame code={%
        \draw[tcbcolframe] ([xshift=5mm]frame.north west)-|+(-5mm,-4mm);
        \draw[tcbcolframe] ([xshift=-5mm]frame.north east)-|+(5mm,-4mm);
        \draw[tcbcolframe] ([xshift=5mm]frame.south west)-|+(-5mm,4mm);
        \draw[tcbcolframe] ([xshift=-5mm]frame.south east)-|+(5mm,4mm);
    },
    #1
}

\tikzset{
    corners/.style={%
        path picture={%
            \draw[#1] ([xshift=5mm]path picture bounding box.north west)-|+(-5mm,-4mm);
            \draw[#1] ([xshift=-5mm]path picture bounding box.north east)-|+(5mm,-4mm);
            \draw[#1] ([xshift=5mm]path picture bounding box.south west)-|+(-5mm,4mm);
            \draw[#1] ([xshift=-5mm]path picture bounding box.south east)-|+(5mm,4mm);
        }
    },
    corners/.default={}
}
\newcommand{\mybox}[2][black]{%
\begin{tikzpicture}
\node[minimum width=8cm,minimum height=2cm, font=\Large, corners=#1] (A) {#2};
\end{tikzpicture}%
}

\begin{document}
\mybox{lorem ipsum}
\vspace{1cm}

\mybox[green, line width=1mm]{lorem ipsum}

\begin{corners}
\lipsum[1][1-3]
\end{corners}

\begin{corners}[colframe=red]
\lipsum[1][2-4]
\end{corners}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Based on [@CarLaTeX's answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/682844), this one

- Supports using `x=<dimen>, y=<dimen>` to change the corner size,
- Makes sure each line segment is drawn only once. (Previously horizontal segments were drawn twice.)

```tex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}

\newcommand{\mybox}[2][black]{%
  \begin{tikzpicture}
    \node[rectangle, minimum width=8cm, minimum height=2cm, font=\Large] (A) {#2};
    \draw[x=.3cm, y=.4cm, line width = 3pt, #1]
      (A.north west) +( 1,0) -- (A.north west) -- +(0,-1) 
      (A.north east) +(-1,0) -- (A.north east) -- +(0,-1) 
      (A.south west) +( 1,0) -- (A.south west) -- +(0, 1)
      (A.south east) +(-1,0) -- (A.south east) -- +(0, 1)
      ;
   \end{tikzpicture}%
}

\begin{document}
\mybox{lorem ipsum}
\bigskip

\mybox[red, x=1.5cm, y=.2cm]{lorem ipsum}
\bigskip

\mybox[cyan!50, dotted, x=.5cm, y=.5cm, rounded corners=.2cm]{lorem ipsum}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: No. You introduce a coordinates distortion. I am looking for a way to do `\draw (1cm,2pt) -- +(a,0)` or `\draw (3in,4mm) -- +(0,a)` with `a` equal simply to `.3`. Perhaps I should ask a new question regarding this. I am afraid that your answer doesn't introduce a new way for the original question.

Comment: muzimuzhiZ and @CarLaTeX Silly me. I just learned that I have already [asked about it before](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/668917/).

Comment: A coordinates distortion? only sort of. Any coordinates with explicit units are not distorted. To use `a` in `\draw (1cm,2pt) -- +(a,0)`, `a` must be a `pgfmath` function declared either by `\pgfmathdeclarefunction` or tikz `math` libraray syntax or `/tikz/declare function` key.  But if using `\a` is also supported, then `\a` can be either of a normal LaTeX command or length.